# Closure Compiler not generating minified file after upgrade

Tags: google-closure-compiler

This works perfectly with compiler version 2013.11.18:

```
java -jar C:/closure/compiler_v20131118.jar 
--compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMISATIONS
--warning_level=VERBOSE 
--jscomp_off=externsValidation
--summary_detail_level=3
--externs C:\path\externs.js 
--create_source_map C:\path\min.map.js 
--output_wrapper "%output%//# sourceMappingURL=urlToMap
--source_map_format V3 
--js C:\path\file1.js 
--js C:\path\file2.js 
--js_output_file C:\path\min.js 
--version 2>&1
```

But the minified file doesn't get created with compiler version 2016.05.17:

```
java -jar C:/closure/compiler_v20160517.jar 
--compilation_level ADVANCED 
--warning_level=VERBOSE 
--jscomp_off=externsValidation
--summary_detail_level=3
--externs C:\path\externs.js 
--create_source_map C:\path\min.map.js
--output_wrapper "%output%//# sourceMappingURL=urlToMap
--source_map_format V3 
--js C:\path\file1.js 
--js C:\path\file2.js 
--js_output_file C:\path\min.js 
--version 2>&1
```

I only get this output in the console:

```
Closure Compiler (http://github.com/google/closure-compiler)
Version: v20160517
Built on: 2016/05/18 16:21
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are redirecting standard error. My guess is you are swallowing the real error message that would tell you the problem.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth What can I do to get the real error message?

Comment: Remove the `2>&1` part of your command - that's redirecting standard error.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth I removed the 2>&1 and the output is exactly the same. No error message , just the 'version' and 'built on' lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot has changed with the compiler from 2013 to 2016. This wiki page has some of the more important changes:

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Managing-Dependencies

As a data point here is an example compile command that is working for me:

```
java -jar ../javascript/closure-compiler/build/compiler.jar
--entry_point=goog:myphysicslab.sims.pendulum.DoublePendulumApp
--compilation_level=SIMPLE --define=goog.DEBUG=true --define=goog.LOCALE='de'
--define=myphysicslab.lab.util.UtilityCore.ADVANCED=false --generate_exports
--js=../closure-library/ --js=src --jscomp_error=accessControls
--jscomp_error=ambiguousFunctionDecl --jscomp_error=checkTypes
--jscomp_error=checkVars --jscomp_error=const --jscomp_error=constantProperty
--jscomp_error=fileoverviewTags --jscomp_error=globalThis
--jscomp_error=invalidCasts --jscomp_error=misplacedTypeAnnotation
--jscomp_error=missingProperties --jscomp_error=missingProvide
--jscomp_error=missingRequire --jscomp_error=missingReturn
--jscomp_error=newCheckTypes --jscomp_error=strictModuleDepCheck
--jscomp_error=suspiciousCode --jscomp_error=typeInvalidation
--jscomp_error=undefinedNames --jscomp_error=undefinedVars
--jscomp_error=unknownDefines --jscomp_error=uselessCode
--jscomp_error=visibility --language_in=ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT
--dependency_mode=STRICT --warning_level=VERBOSE
```

Most likely you need to add the `--entry_point` and `--dependency_mode` options.

Here is an example command using advanced-compile and output_wrapper:

```
java -jar ../javascript/closure-compiler/build/compiler.jar
--entry_point=goog:myphysicslab.sims.pendulum.DoublePendulumApp
--compilation_level=ADVANCED --define=goog.DEBUG=true
'--define=goog.LOCALE='\''en'\'''
--define=myphysicslab.lab.util.UtilityCore.ADVANCED=true --generate_exports
--js=../closure-library/ --js=src --jscomp_error=accessControls
--jscomp_error=ambiguousFunctionDecl --jscomp_error=checkTypes
--jscomp_error=checkVars --jscomp_error=const --jscomp_error=constantProperty
--jscomp_error=fileoverviewTags --jscomp_error=globalThis
--jscomp_error=invalidCasts --jscomp_error=misplacedTypeAnnotation
--jscomp_error=missingProperties --jscomp_error=missingProvide
--jscomp_error=missingRequire --jscomp_error=missingReturn
--jscomp_error=newCheckTypes --jscomp_error=strictModuleDepCheck
--jscomp_error=suspiciousCode --jscomp_error=typeInvalidation
--jscomp_error=undefinedNames --jscomp_error=undefinedVars
--jscomp_error=unknownDefines --jscomp_error=uselessCode
--jscomp_error=visibility --language_in=ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT
--dependency_mode=STRICT --warning_level=VERBOSE
'--output_wrapper='\''(function(){%output%}).call(window)'\'''
```

You might have some problem with the single quote in your output_wrapper?

To see compiler options:

```
java -jar ../closure-compiler/build/compiler.jar --help
```

That will give some good info on the options, for example:

```
--entry_point VAL                   : A file or namespace to use as the
                                      starting point for determining which
                                      src files to include in the compilatio
                                      n. ES6 and CommonJS modules are
                                      specified as file paths (without the
                                      extension). Closure-library namespaces
                                      are specified with a "goog:" prefix.
                                      Example: --entry_point=goog:goog.Promi
                                      se
```

Comment: I am not using the closure library (goog). Do I need to specify the --entry_point or --dependency_mode flag in this case?

Comment: I'm just guessing but try either 1) give --entry_point of your main function or 2) if using goog.provide() to define namespaces then use "goog:" prefix.  Maybe use --dependency_mode=LOOSE to have compiler keep files without goog.provide symbols.  Compiler needs to know where to start if it is going to be figuring what to keep and what to discard.

Comment: I added the entry_point flag pointed to the main js file and now it creates the minified file. Thank you for your help and the useful link about managing the dependencies.